# Вывод данных из БД в laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Вывожу из базы данных информацию. Выводится нормально все кроме путей к картинкам.

```
<img src= {{ $feed->img }} alt="Product_photo">
```

В VSCode это выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информация в src просто не ставится, причем независимо от наличия и вида кавычек

Отладка в браузере выдает следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из базы вытаскиваю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну а какое-то значение у `$feed->img` вообще есть? Что видно в сгенеренном html-е?

Comment: в том то и дело, что ничего нет. src пустой абсолютно

Comment: Значит `$feed->img` пустой или вообще не существует. Можно еще глянуть в сторону какого-нибудь адблока, который подозрительные картинки режет.

Comment: только сейчас заметил, что вытаскивал из БД не то. Надо было photo, а я брал img, правда от этого ситуация не поменялась. кавычки также не решают проблему. вопрос отредактировал

Comment: Последний скрин это вы так в базе храните? Если да - меняйте, это бред.. Делать надо это во время вывода `{{ asset($feed->photo) }}` и в photo только путь записывать

Comment: не знаю, почему сам не догадался. спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{ asset($feed->photo ?? '/img/logo/logo-remove.png') }}" />
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]